# More elegant way to produce a space python

Tags: python, printing, whitespace

I don't know if this question can be answered. I am new to python. I have been using the command print to create a blank space in the output to the python idle shell.

I was wondering is there an easier or more elegant way of creating this white space in the output or is print the only way this can be done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [new line](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) to the end:

```
print 'hello\n'
print 'hi'
```

Prints:

```
hello

hi
```

This can be very helpful for taking in inputs because you can't just stick a `print` in the middle of an input:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?\n> ")
print "Hello {}!".format(name)
```

When run:

```
What is your name?
> Haidro
Hello Haidro!
```

Comment: Awesome :) was just wondering because it seemed silly to constantly type print each time I wanted a new line. I'm surprised it was so easy and works so well :)